# Determine top keywords in MySql table field using php

Tags: php, mysql, keyword

I have a table in MySql with several different fields, one of them contains a description that could be a couple of paragraphs long.

I am trying to figure out a way to have php automatically go through these description fields and create a list of the top keywords used. I am looking for the top keywords for the entire table, not each post individually.

I know this is a bit of a resource heavy operation, and it wouldn't be run very often anyways.

But I'd like to get a list like this:

```
some x 121
most x 110
frequent x 90
words x 50
```

So that I could see what the top used words are in the description field. Any idea at all where to start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run you query,

1. loop through the records and append descriptions together into 1 big happy string.
2. Then, you can explode by ' ' into array
3. Get array of values using array_count_values()
4. Re-sort in descending order arsort()

**Update**

Sample code too:

```
$string = '';
foreach (your_result_set as one_row) 
{
    $string .= $one_row['text'];
}

$data = explode(' ', $string);
$data = array_count_values($data);
arsort($data);
```

Comment: I didn't use this exact method, but something pretty close. Your answer is what put me on the right track, so I will choose your answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the database one way would be to add triggers to this table that maintains another table with all keywords.

The insert trigger would go through new.description and increment all keywords found

The delete trigger would do the same but for old.description and decrement the keywords

The update trigger would do the same as delete and insert, ie decrease all found in old.description and increase for new.description.

Once you have done and tried these triggers dump all data and re import it to have the trigger do the work on all existing data.

Comment: I don't have any control over the database other than just regular queries, so I can read and write the database and tables.

Comment: Then I don't think you have any other choice than to actually read all the data and start counting :)

You do that every night or as rare as is reasonable, not on demand. Store the result in some other table or in memcache.

Answer (score 0):

there are a few ways you can do this. i'm guessing you dont want to count every word, as words like and,if,it etc will all be meaningless.

also how many rows are we talking?

a simple solution is to create and array called words. loop through each row.
explode the paragraph using " ", which gives you each word. you may also wish to do a str_to_lower first if case is an issue.

loop through and use array_key_exists to see if there is a key if not create it. 
and add a value of one. otherwise incriment the value by one.

this will give you counts of each word.

if this is for a search of a large database it would be worthwhile adding keywords to a seperate table on insert. 
one way i think this would be good is to add the 5 most frequent used words excluding those in the exclude list (and,it,or,a,i etc). and add any word that appears in the keyword table.

there are issues with this. i have this response and dont mention php, sql or query which are what the post related to .maybe it would be worth having tags/keywords added on insert.

Comment: sorry i forgot to say. Run this as a command line operation and cron. it will be intesnive so im guessing at the sites quiete times would be useful.